# why widget get built twice when calling Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(..) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

The `build` function in the class `TestWidget` below get called twice when navigation code executed. The `Test Widget` is printed twice on the console.
Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
 class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Test Widget");
    return new Scaffold(body: new Text("TEST WIDGET"),);
  }
}
```

Navigation code:

```
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRoutes.fieldData);`
```

Route definition:

```
  AppRoutes.fieldData: (context) {
           return new TestWidget(); 
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens because of animation.

When a route gets dragged in the page content is built to get a rendered face to be animated in, and then, when it settles into place, it is re-built again.

You can see it clearly placing a debug break in your build function and try to navigate to such route: it will stop first when the route is about to enter - but still not visible -; then when it settles to place.

Comment: is there a way to prevent it from running twice?